# Issues getting message to send to database through AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create my first AJAX call. All I am trying to do is send a message to my database that will hold a user_id, message, and date.

As of now nothing is even happening when I hit the submit button. Why is this not submitting and I'm not sure if I am creating the ajax call correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

My ajax call

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#$(".contactButton")").on("change", function(){
                $user = this.value;
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "insert_announcements.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "username="+$user, 
                    success: function(text){ 
                        if(text == "Error!"){ 
                            alert("Unable to get user info!"); 
                            $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                            $(".announcement_success").show();
                            $('.announcement_success').html('Payment Status Changed!');
                            $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                            alert(data);
                        } else { 
                            var txtArr = text.split('|');
                        } 
                    }, 
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                        alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown); 
                    } 
                });
            });
        });
```

My form

```
<div class="announcement_success"></div>
    <p>Add New Announcement</p>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="insert_announcements" >
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="announcement_message "name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
            <label for="contactButton">
                <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Add Announcement" id="submit">
            </label>
        </form>
```

PHP file insert_announcements

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO announcements (user_id, message, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
    if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {
        // Check Errors for prepare
         die('Announcement INSERT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->bind_param('isi', $announcement_user_id, $announcement_message)) {
        // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('Announcement INSERT bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
        die('Announcement INSERT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
        echo "Announcement was added successfully!";
    else
    {
         echo "Announcement Failed!";
    }
```

Comment: why are you using  $("#member").on("change"  ? there is no element with id as member. $(".contactButton").on("click" to use onclick event of Add Announcement button.

Comment: I just noticed that as you commented. I changed to `$(".contactButton")` and still nothing is happening.

Comment: there is a console tab below in when you press F12(developer tools) in chrome. You   will be able to see your error there. Check those errors and paste them here.

Comment: Your `data` in the ajax-call should be `data: { username: $user }`

Comment: @HarishLalwani There aren't any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Code - When clicking on Add announcement button a ajax call is made to http://localhost/insert_announcements.php.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".contactButton").on("click", function(){
            $user = this.value;
            $.ajax({ 
                url: "insert_announcements.php", 
                type: "POST",
                data: "userid="+$('#userid').val()+"&msg="+$('#announcement_message').val(), , 
                success: function(text){ 
                    if(text == "Error!"){ 
                        alert("Unable to get user info!"); 
                        $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                        $(".announcement_success").show();
                        $('.announcement_success').html('Payment Status Changed!');
                        $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                        alert(data);
                    } else { 
                        var txtArr = text.split('|');
                    } 
                }, 
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                    alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown); 
                } 
            });
        });
    });
```

This should be your html -

```
   <form action="" method="POST" id="insert_announcements" >
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="announcement_message"name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        <input type="text" id="userid" value="" placeholder="user id">
        <label for="contactButton">
            <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Add Announcement" id="submit">
        </label>
    </form>
```

Now code for php accordingly -

```
  $stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO announcements (user_id, message, date) VALUES (mysqli_escape_string($_POST['userid']), mysqli_escape_string($_POST['msg']), NOW())");
```